# C# Web API GET with multiple, comma-separated parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

How to implement in C# (.NET Core or MVC) a `GET` request if I have multiple parameters, but some of them can be comma-separated?

Like this

```
/Product?min=20&size=large&brand=nike,reebok,adidas
```

Comment: Pick whatever method that suits our needs. I.e. clarifying why  `String.Split` on "brand" parameter is not working for you and what in particular you want to achieve would greatly help with getting useful answer.

Comment: Try this:https://www.strathweb.com/2017/07/customizing-query-string-parameter-binding-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass a list via query string you call the api like this:

`/Product?min=20&size=large&brand=nike&brand=reebok&brand=adidas`

And your ActionResult would look like

```
public ActionResult Get([FromQuery]int min, [FromQuery]string[] brand)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the brand parameter as a single string, and in your action you can do

```cs
var brands = brand.Split(",");
```